# Google Sheets IMPORTHTML for multiple toggle tables

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the **IMPORTHTML** function in a Google Sheet cell to import prices of options for a security from a website:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/spy/options","table")
```

The website displays the first few tables by default, while the remaining tables must be toggled **SHOWN** in order for the table data to be shown. The Google Sheets function imports only the default toggled tables, I would like to import all the tables if possible. Is there a method to accomplish this using the **IMPORTHTML** function, or is a script required?

---

**EDIT**
Following the suggestion from [Александр Ермолин](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10805162/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D0%95%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD) to limit the query in the answer below I have used:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/SPY/options?countrycode=US&showAll=True","table")
```

However, the table(s) are too large for the function, which returns **Error maximum size exceeded**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace used URL by this: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/SPY/options?countrycode=US&showAll=True

Comment: Ah, yes of course, /facepalm. Now the data is too large to import for the Google function, however: Error
Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size.